# Simulate browers' defalut "Unable to Connect" error in httpd config for specific virtual host

Tags: apache

I have a task to simulate browsers' default UNABLE TO CONNECT error while connecting to working fine server but via specific host/domain.

For example our server is 1.1.1.1 and we have two domains: one.com and two.com

When reach the server trough one.com browser display it' default unable to connect error page (not HTTP 404 from the server)

When we use two.com we process request as regular virtualhost

Comment: Every browser uses a unique design of such internal error page. It is impossible to mimic that such that no difference is seen.

Comment: Yes I mean to simulate the apache is down when it refers to the specific virtualhost

Comment: As said: not possible in such manner, that the user cannot tell the difference. Best is simply not to reply at all to a request.

Comment: if I do not reply apache runs default virtualhost with 'apache is function normally'

Comment: Well, then you server did reply, didn't it?